# Efficient way to generate Time Slots for a schedule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `#MySchedule` with columns `StartTime`, `EndTime` and `duration`.

What I need is a query to get all time Slots for each row in MySchedule between these StartTime and EndTime based on the duration column.

#### MySchedule table:

```
create table #MySchedule
(
startTime datetime, 
endtime datetime,
duration int
)

insert into #MySchedule
select '1/3/15 10:00 AM' startTime ,'1/3/15 4:00 PM' endTime ,15 duration 
union all 
select '1/4/15 10:00 AM' startTime ,'1/4/15 2:00 PM' endTime ,30 duration 
union all 
select '1/5/15 10:00 AM' startTime ,'1/5/15 4:00 PM' endTime ,45 duration
```

#### Expected output:

```
    Slots   StartTime           EndTime
    1       '1/3/15 10:00 AM'   '1/3/15 10:15 AM'
    2       '1/3/15 10:15 AM'   '1/3/15 10:30 AM'
    3       '1/3/15 10:30 AM'   '1/3/15 10:45 AM'
    4       '1/3/15 10:45 AM'   '1/3/15 11:00 AM'
    5       '1/3/15 11:00 AM'   '1/3/15 11:15 AM'
    .       ...                 ...
    .       '1/3/15 3:45 PM'    '1/3/15 4:00 PM'
    ---------------------------------------------
    .       '1/4/15 10:00 AM'   '1/4/15 10:30 AM'
    .       '1/4/15 10:30 AM'   '1/4/15 11:00 AM'
    .       ...                 ...
    .       '1/4/15 13:30 AM'   '1/4/15 14:00 PM'
    ---------------------------------------------
    .       '1/5/15 10:00 AM'   '1/5/15 10:45 AM'
    .       '1/5/15 10:45 AM'   '1/5/15 11:30 AM'
    .       ...                 ...
    .       '1/5/15 15:15 AM'   '1/5/15 16:00 PM'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for up to 100 intervals. It can be easily expanded to 1000 by adding another `CROSS JOIN inc`, and so on for 10.000 ...

It supposes that the duration is in minutes.

- CTE inc creates a derived table with 10 rows with the ten 1.
- CTE list `CROSS JOIN` CTE inc twice and creates 10*10 rows.
- It also creates a list of number from 1 to 100 (or 1000...) with `ROW_NUMBER()`.
- These numbers are then added to @starttime until it reach @endtime.

#### Query:

```
DECLARE @schedule TABLE(Id int identity(0, 1), StartTime datetime2, EndTime datetime2, Duration int);
INSERT INTO @schedule(StartTime, EndTime, Duration) VALUES
    ('20150103 10:00', '20150103 16:00', 15)
    , ('20150104 10:00', '20150104 14:00', 30)
    , ('20150105 10:00', '20150105 16:00', 45);


WITH inc AS (
    SELECT n FROM (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as i(n)
), list AS(
    SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM inc i10
    CROSS JOIN inc i100
    --CROSS JOIN inc i1000
)
SELECT s.id, l.n
    , DATEADD(minute, s.duration*(n-1), s.StartTime) as StartTime
    , DATEADD(minute, s.duration*n, s.StartTime) as EndTime
    , DATEDIFF(minute, s.StartTime, s.EndTime)/s.Duration
FROM @schedule s
INNER JOIN list l ON
      l.n <= DATEDIFF(minute, s.StartTime, s.EndTime)/s.Duration
ORDER BY s.Id, l.n
```

#### Output:

```
StartTime                   | EndTime
2015-01-03 10:00:00.0000000 | 2015-01-03 10:15:00.0000000
2015-01-03 10:15:00.0000000 | 2015-01-03 10:30:00.0000000
...                         | ...
2015-01-03 15:30:00.0000000 | 2015-01-03 15:45:00.0000000
2015-01-03 15:45:00.0000000 | 2015-01-03 16:00:00.0000000
----------------------------|----------------------------    
2015-01-04 10:00:00.0000000 | 2015-01-04 10:30:00.0000000
2015-01-04 10:30:00.0000000 | 2015-01-04 11:00:00.0000000
...                         | ...
2015-01-04 13:00:00.0000000 | 2015-01-04 13:30:00.0000000
2015-01-04 13:30:00.0000000 | 2015-01-04 14:00:00.0000000
----------------------------|----------------------------    
2015-01-05 10:00:00.0000000 | 2015-01-05 10:45:00.0000000
2015-01-05 10:45:00.0000000 | 2015-01-05 11:30:00.0000000
...                         | ...
2015-01-05 14:30:00.0000000 | 2015-01-05 15:15:00.0000000
2015-01-05 15:15:00.0000000 | 2015-01-05 16:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but what is purpose of " SELECT n FROM (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as i(n) ) " 10 values

Comment: I have added more info in the answer. You can execute the select 1 alone to see the output.

Comment: if you try your query for the above input table it generate wrong values :(

Comment: lets say for Input date 1/3/15 slots should only have interval of 5 mins but query generate 3 type of slots against date 1/3/15. one with 5 mins  duration, second with 30 and 3rd with 45

Comment: run this query 3 times for 15, 30 and 45 intervals. update your sample if something is missing

Comment: no nothing is missing in sample data but yes i modified required output for more clearance.

Comment: there are more than 3 different values in my real scenario. Do you think only option we have is one by one looping for all values?

Comment: see new updated query